# How to implement 'NSTableview Delegate' method?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

How to implement 'NSTableview Delegate' method in MAC OSX 10.4 & above.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

The same way you implement it on 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.5, and 10.6 (some 10.5 and 10.6 methods may not be available on 10.4). See the [Delegates and Data Sources subsection of the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide's Communicating with Objects section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html).

(Hint: A more specific question will get you a more specific answer. Try reading Matt Gemmell's excellent article titled "[What Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?".)